# Fill a list with pyspark dataframe without for loop

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I wrote a spark code to fill a list with all the optional dates-flight prices combinations.
I use a large parquet file that stores over a million flight searches to fill the list with prices.

My source df without any changes looks like this:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+----+-----+---+
|             request|            response|year|month|day|
+--------------------+--------------------+----+-----+---+
|[[[KTW, ROM, 2022...|                [[]]|2022|    5| 25|
|[[[TLV, OTP, 2022...|[[[false, [185.74...|2022|    5| 25|
|[[[TLV, LJU, 2022...|                [[]]|2022|    5| 25|
|[[[TLV, NYC, 2022...|[[[false, [509.35...|2022|    5| 25|
|[[[IST, DSA, 2022...|                [[]]|2022|    5| 25|
+--------------------+--------------------+----+-----+---+
```

Schema is:

```
root
 |-- request: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Segments: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- Origin: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- Destination: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- FlightTime: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- Cabin: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- MarketId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- response: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- results: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- IsTwoOneWay: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- PriceInfo: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Price: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Currency: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- Segments: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- Duration: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- Flights: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- Origin: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- Destination: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- Carrier: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- Departure: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- Arrival: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- Duration: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- FlightNumber: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- DestinationCityCode: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- OriginCityCode: string (nullable = true)
 |-- year: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- month: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- day: integer (nullable = true)
```

I have a function that returns a list with every possible date combination in a month.
I iterate over the dataframe (after filtering the origin-destination) for every date combination.

The code is:

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from itertools import combinations
import datetime

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Practice").master("local[*]").config("spark.executor.memory", "70g").config("spark.driver.memory", "50g").config("spark.memory.offHeap.enabled",True).config("spark.memory.offHeap.size","16g").getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.parquet('spark-big-data\parquet_example.parquet')

df = df.withColumn('fs_origin',df.request.Segments.getItem(0)['Origin'])
df = df.withColumn('fs_destination',df.request.Segments.getItem(0)['Destination'])
df = df.withColumn('fs_date',df.request.Segments.getItem(0)['FlightTime'])
df = df.withColumn('ss_origin',df.request.Segments.getItem(1)['Origin'])
df = df.withColumn('ss_destination',df.request.Segments.getItem(1)['Destination'])
df = df.withColumn('ss_date',df.request.Segments.getItem(1)['FlightTime'])
df = df.filter((df["fs_origin"] == 'TLV') & (df["fs_destination"] == 'NYC') & (df["ss_origin"] == 'NYC') & (df['ss_destination']=='TLV'))
df = df.withColumn('full_date',F.concat_ws('-', df.year,df.month,df.day)).persist()
df =df.filter(F.size('response.results') > 0)

def get_all_dates_in_month():
    start = datetime.datetime.strptime("2022-06-01", "%Y-%m-%d")
    end = datetime.datetime.strptime("2022-07-10", "%Y-%m-%d")
    date_generated = [start + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, (end-start).days+1)]
    date_generated = [date_obj.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for date_obj in date_generated]

    combinations_res = combinations(date_generated, 2)
    return list(combinations_res)

dates_list = get_all_dates_in_month()

res =[]
 
for date in dates_list:
    df_date = df.filter((df['fs_date']==date[0]+'T00:00:00') & (df['ss_date']==date[1]+'T00:00:00'))

    if df_date.count()==0:
        res.append([date, 0])
        
    else:
        df_date = df_date.sort(F.unix_timestamp("full_date", "yyyy-M-d").desc())
        latest_day = df_date.collect()[0]['full_date']

        df_date = df_date.filter(df_date['full_date']==latest_day)
        df_date = df_date.withColumn("exploded_data", F.explode("response.results"))
        df_date = df_date.withColumn(
                    "price",
                    F.col("exploded_data").getItem('PriceInfo').getItem('Price') # either get by name or by index e.g. getItem(0) etc
                )
        res.append([date, df_date.sort(df_date.price.asc()).collect()[0]['price']])


df.unpersist()
spark.catalog.clearCache()

print(*res,sep='\n')
```

The response is like so:

```
[('2022-06-01', '2022-06-02'), 1210.58]
[('2022-06-01', '2022-06-03'), 856.38]
[('2022-06-01', '2022-06-04'), 746.58]
[('2022-06-01', '2022-06-05'), 638.28]
[('2022-06-01', '2022-06-06'), 687.28]
[('2022-06-01', '2022-06-07'), 654.78]
[('2022-06-01', '2022-06-08'), 687.28]
[('2022-06-01', '2022-06-09'), 687.28]
[('2022-06-01', '2022-06-10'), 1241.63]
[('2022-06-01', '2022-06-11'), 773.18]
[('2022-06-01', '2022-06-12'), 773.18]
[('2022-06-01', '2022-06-13'), 697.98]
...
...
```

The problem I have is that it takes around 4 minutes to produce the response, and I'm sure there is a much efficient way of doing it instead of iterating over 400 possible dates in the list.

I need to find a way of creating the list and when I iterate over the dataframe, once I find a matching flight (from all the possible dates) it appends it to the list, and this way I don't need to go through the dataframe 400 times.
I don't know how to do it or how to make the code more efficient if possible.
Thanks!

Comment: At least 5 rows of input would help to recreate this issue but overall you can try first having min price over full_date in fs and ss date partition and then getting the last value with the group by on fs and ss date

Comment: why do descending sort and take a `collect()`? it's a simple `max()`.

Comment: there are ways to do the whole thing without iterating. if you can share a sample input data, we can test the solution(s).

Comment: edited, I added input and schema. thanks

Comment: Could you illustrate in sample data by including the matching records of your expected output + description how you are calculating `[('2022-06-01', '2022-06-02'), 1210.58]` and 
`[('2022-06-01', '2022-06-03'), 856.38]`?   You can truncate only the part that is unrelated to the calculation but try not to omit any data in sample that is required to the calculation.